# What happened to the dragon Daenerys rode off on?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the episode *The Dance of Dragons* one of the three dragons flies Daenerys away from her Sons of the Harpy attackers, getting wounded in the process.

In the following episode *Mother's Mercy*, after the dragon lands Daenerys is found and captured by Dothraki raiders but the wounded dragon has yet to appear again.

Was it killed by the Dothraki? Is it licking its wounds somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spoilers alert:** This answer will contain spoilers for those who haven't watched season 6. Due to the nature of the question, the whole answer will have to be enclosed in spoiler tags which is something I'd rather not do. Therefore read ahead on your own hazard.

---

Daenerys was not with Drogon when she was abducted by the Dothraki.

Afterwards, she was taken to Vaes Dothrak where she managed to kill the Khals and unite the Dothraki under her command.

In the episode, [*Blood of my Blood*](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_of_My_Blood), she starts moving towards Meereen. At some point in her journey, Daenerys senses presence of her child Drogon and goes away for a while. When she returns, she returns on Drogon's back. The scene is pictured below:

[image]

She then arrives in Meereen with Drogon to meet with her besieged councillors.

Afterwards in [*Battle of Bastards*](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Bastards_(episode)), she defeats the Slaver fleet while riding Drogon and her Dothraki cleaned Meereen from Rebels.

So it appears, Drogon spent sometime healing from his wounds at an undisclosed location and then rejoined with his mother who was already going back to Meereen. He is well and alive, and as of [*The Winds of Winter*](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Winds_of_Winter), flying back to Westeros with Daenerys and her invasion fleet. Pictured below, Drogon and his siblings flying over Targaryen fleet on its way to Westeros:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The fate of Drogon in the TV series is still up in the air.  If this follows the book series, he is alive and well, and will most likely be reuniting with Dany in the near future.

Here's the same end scene in Dance:

> As the western sky turned the color of a blood bruise, she heard the sound of approaching horses. Dany rose, wiped her hands on her ragged undertunic, and went to stand beside her **dragon**. That was how Khal Jhaqo found her, when half a hundred mounted warriors emerged from the drifting smoke.

Comment: So the Dothraki in the novel actually witnessed Dany with the dragon...  there should be no question about who she is.  Unlike the TV series where Dany is alone in the field and during her transport soldiers are talking about the white haired captive as if her identity isn't known.

Comment: @ReeceDodds I'm assuming that setting the hut on fire is replaced by a dragon in the books. My guess is either way it ends up being the same.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that if Dany makes it to Vaes Dothrak she will remember to respect the institute of the Dosh Khaleen and not burn down their huts, unlike the TV version, Kelly C who just wants to see the world burn.

Comment: @Mooz maybe so. I'm starting to lean towards the evil Dany theory, but that's more of a chat discussion.

Comment: @kuhl Ahh, "The Mad Queen" theory. She may be her father's daughter I suppose.

Comment: @ReeceDodds in the books it is Khal Jhaqo with his khalasar that captures Daenerys. He was a bloodrider of Khal Drogo and most certainly knows who Daenerys is.

Comment: Don't worry. The show has been missing/skipping a lot of animals. -Points at the hounds in the Briene's fight- The show just forgot about them, just like about Drogon. Also, note another instance, when Tyrion frees the two dragons, they just go back inside.."Oh yeah, okay thanks but we will just head back for a while, don't watch, bitch." And Tyrion makes a run for it. Point is, show has got some sort of amnesia or something where it keeps forgetting about the animals.